# username not populating in Email template ({!Receiving_User.Username}) customer portal

Tags: email-template, customer-community

I am working on communities customer portal. I have created a email template for reset password for customer. when ever email triggered username is blank
for username am using :`{!Receiving_User.Username}` merge field 
if i replace it with : `{!user.username }` it populating current user username  but i `need customer username`  please help me on this

FYI:  For portal users, the Receiving_User is actually pulling fields from the Contact object, not from the User object. Even the standard fields are from the Contact, not from the User.

bellow is my code:

Dear {!Receiving_User.FirstName} {!Receiving_User.LastName}, ----> first name and last name  populating correct

Username:{!Receiving_User.Username}

Login with temporary password link generated by system:{!Community_Url}

Please log into your account with the credentials listed above. You will be asked to set a new password when you log in. If you have any questions, please contact me.

Best regards,
{!User.FirstName} {!User.LastName}
{!User.Title}
{!User.Phone}
{!User.Email}
{!Organization.Name}

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, the `Receiving_User` is actually a `Contact` object - this means there is no `Username` field on that Object.
Depending on how you set up your users, I would assume that the `Email` field is actually used for generating usernames for customers. In this case, you can just change `{!Receiving_User.Username}` to `{!Receiving_User.Email}` and this would be merged with the user's username.

If that is not working, what you might do is use a visualforce template with an `apex:component`, supply the `{!Receiving_User.Id}` to the component's controller, query for the `User` with that `ContactId` and then return this `User.Username` to the VF-Email.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. i cant use email instead of username. in visualforce template merge fields like Receiving_User.sending_user wont work

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with Receiving_User.sending_user, but in VF-Templates you can leverage apex and thus you can query for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Communities (based on your comments), the field that you're referencing was used in previous iterations (see "Username" at https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contacts_fields.htm&language=en_US).

Your best bet is to do a minor extension and do a look up of the user based on the contact ID. The User record should have the contact Id linked.

```
select id, userName from User where contactId = :objectVar.id
```

You can see more information on how to use standard controllers here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm. It gives you an example of how to create an sObject record for the standard controller passed (which is what I'm calling "objectVar" in the SOQL query above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I solved it by putting all the text as a link by clicking the transform into link button

[image]